# jquery reset load file back to default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 3 layer `select` use jquery load `option` into `sub-select`

```
country->state->city
```

so if user select usa, the 2nd `select` will load usa's state. than user can select city after select the state.

ex. usa->CA->LA

however if user select usa->CA->LA first than user want to change country to aus

it become aus->select state->LA, the 3rd `select` still stay the same.

Is any way to reset 2nd, 3rd `select` back to default if user change top `select`.

```
$("#country").change(function(){
    switch($("#country").val()){
        case "aus":$("#state").load("aus_state.php");break
        case "uk":$("#state").load("uk_countie.php");break
        case "usa":$("#state").load("us_state.php");break
    }
});
```

how to remove the load files back to default?

Comment: I think you are missing the easy solution. On the change event, just empty() the other selects?

Comment: yes, because previous select already load the file

Comment: i mean unload the file, because 3rd selet only change when 2nd select change

Comment: Than empty() the element! `$("#state").empty();`

Comment: i have try empty but here comes a problem my default has set one

<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">State/Counties</option>
but now everything will gone

Comment: and the sub select can't select again

Comment: So add it back in. `$(".second").html('<option>State/Countries</option>');`